# "Семья Дюпон" или "семья Дюпонов"?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "семья Дюпон" или "семья Дюпонов"?

Answer (score 3):

Да, верно, варианты считаются **равноправными**: семья Дюпон и семья Дюпонов, например: История **семьи Дюпон** началась в 1802 году. Надо отметить, что **семья Дюпонов** никогда не бедствовала.

Но следует учесть, что при отсутствии сопровождающих слов (семья, супруги, братья) используется форма мн. числа, например:

"Это лишний раз свидетельствует о том, что у  Морганов, Рокфеллеров, Дюпонов и прочих магнатов монополистического капитала короткая память".

Answer (score 2):

В Словаре грамматических вариантов русского языка говорится, что возможно употребление фамилии как в единственном, так и во множественном числе без какой-либо градации сопровождающих их слов на термины родства, имена, инициалы и т. п., например: ***Семья Муфель*** была очень веселой и жизнерадостной (Н. А. Обухова).

Таким образом, варианты равноправны: *семья Дюпон* и *семья Дюпонов*.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще нормой считается образование по типу "семья Дюпонов". Как и вообще склонение подобных фамилий по общему правилу.

Но в силу традиции отдельные известные фамилии (главным образом - французского происхождения) в подобных конструкциях сохраняют начальную форму.
В данном случае я склоняюсь именно к этому варианту. **Семья Дюпон**.

(+)

Посмотрел ответы и понял, что тут несколько разные случаи объединяются.

Семья Дюпонов - это семья в прямом смысле, ячейка общества: папа Дюпон, мама Дюпон и их дети Дюпоны.
Семья Дюпон - это влиятельная группа лиц, объединенных общими экономическими интересами, платформой, построенной в основном на родственных связях.
(субъективно пока)
Так что у нас - **семья Дюпон**. А пример у Sibylla несколько сомнителен по смыслу.
Могу, конечно, ошибаться, но чем больше думаю, тем более уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь: при слове семья фамилия обычно ставится в форме единственного числа, например: семья Оппенгейм, семья Гофман-сталь.